# Why does this error occur?

Tags: perl, json

I am getting this error

```
Argument "\\x{61}" isn't numeric in numeric comparison (<=>)
```

from

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON::PP;
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json = JSON::PP->new->allow_nonref;
$json = $json->utf8;

my $data = {
        12 => {
                a => 1,
                b => 2,
        },
        1 => {
                    x => 3,
        },
        2 => {
                z => 4,
        }
};

my $json_string = $json->sort_by(sub { $JSON::PP::a <=> $JSON::PP::b })->encode($data);
```

It is suppose to encode the hash to a json string, and then numeric sort the keys `12` `1` `2`.

If the problem can be solved with another JSON parser, then that would be perfectly fine =)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you prefer a numerical sort but want to fall back to a lexicographic sort, use this sort function:

```
$json_string = $json->sort_by(
                    sub {
                        $JSON::PP::a <=> $JSON::PP::b
                                  ||
                        $JSON::PP::a cmp $JSON::PP::b
                    }
                )->encode($data);
```

When the sort keys are not numeric, the numerical comparison (`<=>`) operator will return 0 and the function will perform the lexical comparison (`cmp`) operation.

---

Edit (the above solution still didn't suppress the warnings). A few more tweaks are needed to suppress the warnings. You could say

```
sub {
    no warnings 'numeric';
    $JSON::PP::a <=> $JSON::PP::b || $JSON::PP::a cmp $JSON::PP::b
}
```

Comment: I still get the error =( It have been suggested that it tries to sort the inner keys `a` `b` `z` rather than `12` `1` `2`.

Comment: @Sandra it is sorting on *all* levels; first "1", "12", and "2". Then under the key "12", it is sorting 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: Very impressive! Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 4):

Since `aaa bbb a2` are not number, you probably want a lexicographic sort.

Try replacing `<=>` with `cmp`:

```
 $json_string = $json->sort_by(sub { $JSON::PP::a cmp $JSON::PP::b })->encode($data);
```

Comment: Updated the post. I get the same error when the keys are numbers.

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting: note that the hex value 0x61 (implied by the error message `"\\x{61}"`) is the ASCII letter "a", so the keys in question are probably the most deeply nested ones (a, b, x, z).

Comment: @maerics : Very interesting! How can I get it to sort on the outer keys?

Comment: @Sandra: I don't know, the [Perl JSON::PP sort_by documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm#sort_by) is light on details...

Comment: Sidenote: numbers and strings are different in Perl/JSON: `perl -MJSON -le 'print to_json({ one => 1, two => "2" })'` ⤑ `{"one":1,"two":"2"}`