# How to decode JSON object and iterate over it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255802/why-does-this-error-occur) post I learned how to encode an object on the server side, and now I would like to decode it on the client side.

On the client side I do

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/cgi-bin/ajax_sort.pl",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    data: { "column" : this.id },

    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        showError('responseText: ' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        showError('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
        showError('errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
    },

    success: function(result){
        if (result.error) {
            showError(result.error);
        } else {

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

        }
    }
});
```

**Question**

Does `obj` now contain the decoded JSON data?

If so, the object looks like this one the server side (output from Perl's `Data::Dumper`)

```
$VAR1 = {
          '127' => {
                     'owners' => [
                                   'm'
                                 ],
                     'users' => [
                                  'hh',
                                  'do'
                                ],
                     'date_end' => '24/05-2011',
                     'title' => 'dfg',
                     'date_begin' => '24/05-2011',
                     'members_groups' => [],
                     'type' => 'individuel'
                   },
          '276' => {
                     ...
```

**Question**

Is `obj` indeed contains the decoded JSON, how do I iterate over the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you specified the `dataType: 'json'`, `result` should already contain the Javascript object unserialized from the HTTP response. [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parseJSON) should be unnecessary.

You can loop through it with [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each):

```
success: function(result){
    if (result.error) {
        showError(result.error);
    } else {
        $.each(result, function(key, value) {
            alert(value.title).
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! =) How do I access the array elements in users?

Comment: If you're within the `$.each` callback, you should loop through `value.users`, or use `value.users[0]` to get the first one, etc. I'd suggest you look into documentation on the [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) types, and learn how to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is already a JSON object - parsed by jQuery since you've specified `dataType: "json"` - so you shouldn't be parsing it.

To go over the data, you could do this:

```
for(key in result){
    var curr = result[key];

    //iterate over owners    
     for(var i = 0; i < curr.owners.length; i++){
         alert(curr.owners[i]);
     }

    //iterate over users    
     for(var i = 0; i < curr.users.length; i++){
         alert(curr.users[i]);
     }

     alert(curr.data_end);
     alert(curr.title);

    //and so on...
}
```

**Update**

I keep forgetting about `$.each()` as shown in lonsomeday's answer - you might want to go with that instead.

Comment: Very interesting point about `datatype`. You write `result` will be a JSON obejct. Is that the same as a JavaScript object?

Comment: @Sandra JSON is a data format that is based on a subset of JavaScript and makes use of the object literal notation from JS - so JSON is valid JS. And so, yes, once parsed, the 'JSON' object is indeed a JS object. I used the term 'JSON object' to indicate that the object would have been created by parsing the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the data type of your AJAX request as JSON. jQuery will automatically "decode" this and create an object out of it.

You can immediately access the data via `alert( result[127] );`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over obj's members using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```
for(var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    alert(key + "=" + value);
}
```

*Note:* There should be little reason for you to want to iterate over the members of a JSON object. JSON is intended as a serialization format where both sides (client and server) know its structure. If you can help what data is transmitted, obj should be an array on its outmost scope.